# OpenShift Redirect Loop between www and non-www

Tags: redirect, openshift

I'm experiencing an infinite redirect loop when I try to access my site. The redirect loop seems to be between the non-www version and the www version.

My DNS has a URL Redirect set for http://domain.tld to www.domain.tld. Then www.domain.tld has a CNAME record for app-namespace.rhcloud.com.

For the app I added the alias www.domain.tld

I've also tried to add an alias for domain.tld, but that doesn't help.

Is there something I'm missing? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm hosting a laravel 5 project on openshift.  www and non-www are tricky but I finally got it working with a simple 2 part solution...

1. since you can't use non-www for a cname, make it an A-record to 174.129.25.170 and they will add the www.  That's all they seem to do.  Weird, I know.
2. Use this in your .htaccess It seems to work better in cloud situations.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was due to a redirect from www.domain.tld to domain.tld that was caused by a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

Removing this resolved the issue.

Comment: Facing this exact problem. What is the location of the .htaccess file in Openshift from where you removed these lines?

Comment: That was in the root of my project. I took that from a template some time ago.